# print incremental count variable val within while

Tags: c++, while-loop

Below is what I currently have; I am not sure why I cannot just print the value, incrementally with the below; i.e. 1,2,3.. etc. I have also tried  `cout<<count;`

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {char count;


     while(count<=10)
     {
     cout<<"My name is Bill"<<endl;
     cout << "The # is:" <<count<<endl;
     cout << count++;
     }
     }
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? What do you want it to do differently?

Comment: Could you please explain a little more?  It is very unclear to me what you are asking

Comment: You use `count` uninitialized and you need to cast it for it to be visible: `cout << static:cast<int>(count++);`

Answer (score 4):

`count` is uninitialized. Since you want to start from `1`, you should initialize it that way. And, you should use an integer.

```
int count=1;
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You should declare `count` as an `int` and initialize it:

   ```
   int count = 0;
   ```

   I suggest you learn about the different primitive data types that C++ has. Using the correct type for what you want to do will save you a lot of headache.
2. You are incrementing **and** printing out with one command:

   ```
   cout << count++;
   ```

   Instead, you only need to increment:

   ```
   count++;
   ```